# Java String change order of words

Tags: java

I have a one string :

```
String s = "1 = Nick , 2 = Jack , 3 = Sarah , 4 = Katherina";
```

I want to change order of words like that :

```
String s = "Nick = 1 , Jack = 2 , Sarah = 3 , Katherina = 4";
```

How I change the place number and name ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
String s = "1 = Nick , 2 = Jack , 3 = Sarah , 4 = Katherina";
s = s.replaceAll("(\\d+) = (\\w+)", "$2 = $1");
System.out.println(s);
```

`replaceAll` takes two arguments `regex` and `replacement`. In first argument we want to pass regex that will match

- one or more digits - `\\d` represents one digit,
  `\\d+` represents one or more digits
  we can also place it in group by surrounding it with parenthesis `(\\d+)` - this will be **1st group**
- next should be space, equation mark and another space
- next, one or more characters - `\\w` represents any character in range `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` or `_`
  `\\w+` will represent one or more characters of `\\w` class
  we will also place it in group `(\\w+)` - this will be **2nd group**

Now in `replacement` part we can use groups with `$x` where `x` is group number.
So if we write it as `"$2 = $1"` it will mean that we want to use matched part stored in group 2 (name) then append `" = "` and then append matched part stored in group 1 (ID).

Comment: @Pshemo is right. Try removing the third group altogether. I think you'll find it works.

Comment: I updated your answer with my simpler version or regex and added some informations. Hope you don't mind. Also my English is way from perfect so feel free to rephrase it (it is your answer :D)

Comment: Thanks for your editing I didn't have time to explain answer yesterday :))

Answer (score 1):

I know there is a good answer with regex, i'm just providing an alternative without (complex) regex for comparrison to show why regex is the better/simpler solution for this answer.

```
String s = "1 = Nick , 2 = Jack , 3 = Sarah , 4 = Katherina";
s = s.replace(" ", "");
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
String[] s2 = s.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
    String[] s3 = s2[i].split("=");
    if (i == s2.length - 1) {
        out.append(s3[1]).append(" = ").append(s3[0]);
    } else {
        out.append(s3[1]).append(" = ").append(s3[0]).append(" , ");
    }
}
System.out.print(out);
```

Comment: You could make this simpler also as you don't need the special case for `if (i==0)`. Just put the space after the comma.

Comment: i did a quick mock up didnt really proof anything i wrote and yes it has very basic regex, i meant to aviod a purely regex solution.

Comment: While it works now I updated your answer to change concatenating of strings in loop to append them to previously created StringBuilder. This prevents creating new StringBuilders in each loop iteration to concatenate strings. Now I can upvote it your answer :)